# Unable to Access RestResource via jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, apexrest

## Question

I am trying to access an endpoint I setup in Apex.
The class is pretty simple:

```
@RestResource (urlMapping = '/MyService/*')
global class MyServiceApexClass {

  @HttpGet
  global static My_Object__c doGet() {
    return new My_Object__c (Id = '1234');
  }
}
```

My jQuery Ajax call looks like this:

```
var sessionId = document.cookie.match(/(^|;\s*)sid=(.+?);/)[2];
$.ajax({
  url: (sitePrefix + '/' + servicePath),
  type: 'GET',
  beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
  },
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR); },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }
});
```

Error is **always** being called and I am never getting any type of success.  The output is pretty basic (see below).  If I check the *Network* tab in Firefox/Chrome I see that I am getting back a 302 response.

Any suggestions?

## Sample Response

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 10 more… }
```

## Notes

- Site Prefix turns out to be `/`
- The Service Path is `services/apexrest/MyService`

Comment: I switched to loading the Session ID via `var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';` and still have not had luck.

Comment: Just tried [this JSONP solution](http://peterknolle.com/accessing-apex-rest-from-site-com/) and it did not work, either.  I continue to get the same response back from SF.

Comment: Have you tried hitting hte webservice from the REST explorer in the developer workbench? Often a good way to make sure you're getting the request details correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the Apex class listed as an available class for the user's profile. 
For a public REST resource (i.e., no login necessary), that profile is the Force.com Site's guest user profile. You set this by clicking the Public Access Settings button on the Site detail page to get to the Site's guest profile and then enable the class for the profile.  For a non-public REST resource, it is whatever the profile is of the user(s).

Also, if you are in an org with a namespace,  you need to add that to the path in between the `apexrest`and your rest path.

For example, without a namespace it could be the following for a public REST resource:

`https://mycool-developer-edition.na15.force.com/testsite/services/apexrest/v1.0/messages`

With a namespace of myns it would be:

`https://mycool-developer-edition.na15.force.com/testsite/services/apexrest/myns/v1.0/messages`

Additionally, you mention that your site prefix is just '/'.  That won't work for a public REST resource, so maybe it isn't supposed to be a public REST resource.

If you need to access a REST resource as a logged in user, look at the [forcetk library](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit) as it abstracts away much of the lower level (connection, proxy, etc.) details. It includes an apexrest() function.

Comment: The site prefix is coming from `{!$Site.Prefix}`,  so is that incorrect?  If it needs the entire URL how do you resolve the entire URL without hardcoding the full path?

Comment: You need to make sure that you are accessing the URL through the site URL. If you access it as a normal logged in user via the /apex/yourPage, the Site.Prefix will be empty.  If it is accessed through the site URL, it should have the prefix, e.g., https://mycool-developer-edition.na15.force.com/testsite/myPage would return testsite/, but https://na1.salesforce.com/apex/myPage would not.

Comment: Weird, but I guess it works.